# `Return` method dosn't work in protected function

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel 5.2
I want to test if the user was the entry on the page fault, and I want to redirect the user to your last paginate, but I want to do using protected function with resource controller

```
// Resource controller

protected function checkPage($paginate_number){
    $paginate_count = Product::count() / $paginate_number;

    if(isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] > $paginate_count){
        return redirect('/admin/products?page='.$paginate_count);
    }
}

public function index(){
    $paginate_number = 3;
    $this->checkPage($paginate_number);

    $products = Product::paginate($paginate_number);
    return view('admin.products-view')->withProducts($products);         
}
```

But when i use `return redirect(...)` outside protected function it work
How can i use it inside `protected function`?

Comment: where is this defined `redirect()`, that's not a built in php function so it has to be defined before using it.  Also your `if` condition must be true are you certain it is.  And, I am assuming your actually calling it ( not shown in example ), though I don't see the point of returning on a redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found good way to solve this issue with `protected function` because i can't to use redirect with it

**solution**:

```
protected function checkPage($paginate_number){
    $paginate_count = Product::count() / $paginate_number;

    if(isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] > $paginate_count){
        // If needed to create another error page to explain current error
        return abort(404);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use rediret in a function that is not in the route. your checkpage function called as a subfunction, so it not works. and i'm not sure the direct function you use correctly, I usually use the return Redirect::back()`; or`return Redirect::to('url');`